# How can I fix this code for wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to use this code in wordpress theme.

```
    <ul>
  <?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li>
                <span class="l-e-right"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('large-thumb'); ?></a></span>
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                        <time datetime="<?php the_date('j F Y'); ?>"><?php the_date('j F Y'); ?></time>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </li>'
            }
    wp_reset_query();
  ?>
</ul>
```

but there is something wrong!

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'large' (T_STRING), expecting
>   ',' or ';' in

How can I fix this code?

Thanks...

Comment: Unescaped single quote

Comment: You may use `echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '">Link</a>` to avoid all these `<?`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You have not cloded  tags properly.
Try this :

```
 <?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ ?>
       <li>
                <span class="l-e-right"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('large-thumb'); ?></a></span>
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                        <time datetime="<?php the_date('j F Y'); ?>"><?php the_date('j F Y'); ?></time>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </li>
   <?php
            }
    wp_reset_query();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

as a general rule, you fix syntax errors in hard-to-read code by

a) improving the code layout until the error is obvious
b) removing the offending code block and gradually putting it back

Answer (score 0):

Add a `;` at the end of you string (with the generated HTML-Code).